# What does 'subclass' mean in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm reading the [documentation on Vue.extend](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-extend):

> Create a “subclass” of the base Vue constructor. The argument should be an object containing component options.

What does 'subclass' mean in Vue.js?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Object-Oriented Programming in general, "subclass" is the term for a class that inherits functionality from another class.

Although Vue components aren't defined explicitly as classes, the result of `Vue.extend` is a constructor for a Vue component that has inherited the properties from the base Vue constructor. This constructor is what they are referring to as the "subclass" in this case.

Comment: I think 'subclass' is an instance created with an extended Vue constructor and in the other word, this is called 'component' in Vue.js

Is it correct?

Comment: The "subclass" is a constructor (or the definition of a component), not an instance. You need to instantiate it via `new`, to create the actual component instance. Updated my answer to clarify.

Comment: Okey, I definitely understand your answers
thank you very much!